# wc_get_template new template does not showing up

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I use this code in in my plugin file. The content from the original orders.php file is gone that means the filter does work but my own file does not showing up.

I added this code in the plugin main file

```
<?php
define("PLUGIN_DIR_PATH", plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
?>
```

and this code below in the plugin functions file.

The functions.php is located in 
pluginfolder/required/functions.php

```
 <?php
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'q343_get_template', 10, 5 );
function q343_get_template( $located, $template_name,     $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {    
if ( 'myaccount/orders.php' == $template_name ) {
    $located = PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'required/templates/orders.php';
}

return $located;
}
?>
```

The template that I will load is located in
pluginfolder/required/templates/orders.php

Answer (score 2):

plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) will return the current directory.
Not sure where you call this q343_get_template() function if it's on a subdirectory then plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) is returning that subdirectory path.

From WordPress Code Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

> The “plugin” part of the name is misleading – it can be used for any file, and will not return the directory of a plugin unless you call it within a file in the plugin’s base directory.

The safest way is to use define on your root plugin file.

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

Then call the function like this

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'q343_get_template', 10, 5 );
function q343_get_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {    
    if ( 'myaccount/orders.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'required/templates/orders.php';
    }

    return $located;
}
```

Comment: I changed the code but nothing is changed:( I have edit my question with the code that I used

Comment: make sure orders.php is not throwing any fatal error, see debug log

Comment: No I have only a simple echo inside the template